# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

How to check uniform convergence of the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n} $ on $|z|<1.$ Clearly it is power series with radius of convergence as $1$  and power series converges in any compact subset of its domain of convergence on $|z|<1$. How to check its uniform convergence? $M_{n}$ test is not working here. Thanks.

Comment: See proposition 3.1 in this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=xUHDAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cartan+elementary+theory+of+analytic+functions&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQjLSVlsTPAhXMbz4KHULjCgcQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=normally&f=false

Comment: ok i will look it...thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was uniform convergence on the open unit disk, then we would have 
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}a_N\mbox{ where }a_N :=\sup_{|z|\lt 1}\left|\sum_{n=N +1}^{2N}z^n/n\right|. $$
We have the bounds 
$$a_N\geqslant \sup_{0\lt t\lt 1}\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}t^n/n\geqslant  \sup_{0\lt t\lt 1}t^{2N}/2  =1/2        $$
since the sequence $\left(t^n/n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is decreasing.

Comment: What is here $t $?