# Show convergence of $\sum \frac{z^n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that the series $\displaystyle\sum \frac{z^n}{n}$ for $z=1$ diverges, but for all $z \ne 1$ with $|z|=1$ converges. Hint: Estimate $(1-z) \displaystyle\sum_{n=k}^{m} \frac{z^n}{n}$.

The first case $z=1$ is easy, this is just the harmonic series. But I am really stuck with the second part, which is the actually interesting one. First I tried to write $z=re^{i \phi}$, but the hint does not look like this could be useful. Specifically, I don't know how to bring the series in a form such that the hint is even useful.

Edit: To clearify some questions from the comments. The hint has no misprint and I don't see how the question about the uniform convergence of this series on the open unit disk that was posted multiple times in the comments helps me to solve this problem. However, thank you already for your help! There might be a good strategy by applying the Dirichlet test as one of the answers suggests.

Comment: Did you use the hint ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust "Specifically, I don't know how to bring the series in a form such that the hint is even useful."

Comment: Do you know how to multiply a series by a binomial ?

Comment: @Daphna That question deals with convergence in the open disk, so I don't think it applies.

Comment: @Daphna maybe I just don't get it, but I don't see how this other question help me so show the convergence of my series.

Comment: Could it be that you have misprinted and the hint says: "Estimate $(1-z)\sum z^n$"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955269/uniform-convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn)

Comment: @AlanMuniza The question you mentioned deals with the case $|z|<1$.

Comment: @user I just looked it up again and the hint says exactly what I wrote in my question.

Comment: Then I think it is a misprint in the book. This is a clear case for Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @user Now that I know the Dirichlet's test, I agree. However, I suspect that there might be another way to solve it, without the Dirichlet test, as we did not cover the test in our complex analysis course but this is a homework problem from this course.

Comment: Let me know the "official" solution of the problem.

Comment: @user The official solution does not use the Dirac test, but tries to show that the partial sums are a cauchy series, by using the hint.

Comment: @user $|(1-z) \sum_{n=k}^{m} \frac{z^n}{n}| = |\sum_{n=k}^{m} \frac{z^n}{n} - \sum_{n=k+1}^{m+1} \frac{z^n}{n-1}| = |\frac{z^k}{k} - \frac{z^{m+1}}{m} + \sum_{n=k+1}^{m} (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n-1}) z^n| $ then triangular inequality to every term, use the absolute value of z and the telescope sum. Finally you should have an upper bound of 2/k which is a cauchy series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|=1;z\neq1$, we can write $z=e^{i\vartheta};\vartheta\in (0,2\pi) $. Thus the problem reduces to the convergence of the series $$\sum\frac {e^{in\vartheta}}{n}$$

A simple application of [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) suffice to find an answer.

In fact, consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$; $b_n=(e^{i\vartheta})^n$. Then $a_n\searrow 0$; Can you show that $|\sum e^{in\vartheta}$| is bounded?

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the Dirichlet test, I think this was crucial. I did not know that test. Anyway, so far I have not managed to show the boundedness you asked for. It does not help to apply the Triangle inequality.

Comment: @FeWa $\sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\vartheta}=\frac{e^{i(N+1)\vartheta}-1}{e^{i\vartheta}-1}$. Since $\left|\frac{e^{i(N+1)\vartheta}-1}{e^{i\vartheta}-1}\right|\le \frac{2}{|e^{i\vartheta}-1|}<+\infty$ (since $z\neq 1$) we obtain the desired boundedness

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z^k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z^{k+1}}k=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z^k}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{z^k}{k-1}=z-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k(k-1)}-\frac{z^{n+1}}n.$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I don't quite get it yet, how this identity helps me, but I am working on it.